# On youtube i have this certain ads constantly going for the same thing ive blocked them ive went in my settings to see less and its the opposite so?

Tags: youtube

Ok so there's a ad that keep coming on while I'm on youtube so I went to my ad settings and put I wanted to see less of this type of ads well I seen more so I started blocking them and now that's the only ads I see can I do anything about this

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.